# Error upgrading from Rails 3.2.22 to Rails 4.2.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, bundler, gemfile

I am trying to upgrade our app from Rails 3.2.22 to Rails 4.2.4 with Ruby 2.2.3.

Here's what I've done so far:

1. Modified Gemfile to specify `rails, "~> 4.2.4"`
2. `bundle`
3. `bundle update rails`

The full transcript is below.

ActiveRecord is not specified in our Gemfile, so I don't understand what has it locked or where to fix it?

```
Craigs-MacBook-Pro~/Work/mbc(master|✔) % git checkout -b rails-424
Switched to a new branch 'rails-424'
Craigs-MacBook-Pro~/Work/mbc(rails-424|✔) % vim Gemfile
Craigs-MacBook-Pro~/Work/mbc(rails-424|✚1) % bundle
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/........
Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
You have requested:
  rails ~> 4.2.4

The bundle currently has rails locked at 3.2.22.
Try running `bundle update rails`
Craigs-MacBook-Pro~/Work/mbc(rails-424|✚1) % bundle update rails
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/........
Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies............
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activerecord":
  In Gemfile:
    activerecord (< 4.3, >= 3.1) ruby

    activerecord (< 5.0, >= 3.0) ruby

    vestal_versions (>= 0) ruby depends on
      activerecord (~> 3.0) ruby

    activerecord (> 3.0.0) ruby

    rails (~> 4.2.4) ruby depends on
      activerecord (= 4.2.4) ruby
Craigs-MacBook-Pro~/Work/mbc(rails-424|✚1) %
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`vestal_versions` gem has dependency to `ActiveRecord 3.0`.

You need to unspecify version of `vestal_versions` gem in your Gemfile, or specify to `2.0.0` and then:

```
bundle update rails vestal_versions
```

Comment: Ah, so "depends on" was the key phrase there.

Comment: Yes, it got me to the next set of errors, yet.  I can't accept an answer for a few more minutes.